# Where can I find sample Web Server Requests/Response Data

Tags: http, post, get, webserver

Is there any sort of data dump or data set with information from Web Server logs?

The information that I am mainly looking for are:
a) what type of request is it (POST or GET or HTTP or something else)
b) What type of data is being transferred (image, audio, video or text)
c) what is the size of the data that is being transferred

Information such as IP address, URL can be anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Firefox?  If so, you can use the included Web Console tool to view all the HTTP request body being sent from your browser to the server and the response bodies, along with things like the method (GET, POST, etc.).  This would be the same thing that a web server would be logging (except the IP address of the client is always you, obviously).  You should be able to copy all the data and paste it to a file if you want a data dump.

To use the web console, click the orange Firefox button and then Web Developer > Web Console.  Or if you're using an older version or have the Firefox button disabled, it's under the tools menu.

**Edit:** To get the most out of it, you'll want to right click on the console and select Log Request and Response Bodies.  This will get you more information than just the headers.

Comment: I think this will do. But if others have any more ideas, please feel free to share